# I can't add JButtons to a JList in a specific order

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I try to add JButtons in the JList to be like a board game.

Here's my code:

```
public class Board {

public Board() {
    JList list = new JList();
    list.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
    list.setDragEnabled(true);

    Container container = new Container();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    frame.add(container);
    container.add(panel1);

    for (int j = 0; j < 99; j++) {
        list.add(createButton());
    }

    panel2.add(list);
    container.add(panel2);
    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    panel1.setBounds(50, 150, 150, 150);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    panel2.setBounds(650, 150, 500, 500);
    panel2.setBackground(Color.RED);

    frame.setSize(1366, 768);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public JButton createButton() {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    return button;
}
}
```

If I put 100 repetitions I get this: [image]

If I put 99 repetitions i get this:

[image]

**So my question is how can I fill the above board?**

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674268/how-do-i-make-my-custom-swing-component-visible/4674686#4674686) show one way to dray icons around a grid using panels and labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's happening is because you're adding all the buttons to a JList, which isn't really how you're meant to use a JList (usually you modify the *model* backing the list in order to add/remove items from the list). The list is internally doing something that takes up the first slot.

If you change this line:

```
JList list = new JList();
```

to:

```
JPanel list = new JPanel();
```

your layout will work (you have to remove the `setDragEnabled` line as well, and change 99 to 100). Whether there's some capability of JList that you want I'm not sure, but that's why your layout isn't working properly.

Comment: I used JList because I need to make drag and drop later on. Actually i'm creating a battleship game and I can't use JPanel for that according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/defaultsupport.html

Comment: I've always found setting up dnd to be painful, but I dunno, using a JList just seems like the wrong approach.

Comment: I think so too I spent a lot of time trying to make something out of JList.I will see if I can come up with something through JPanel.Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You should create your JList :

```
DefaultListModel dataModel = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(dataModel);
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
```

Set a ListCellRenderer as follows:

```
 final JButton button = createButton();
    list.setCellRenderer(new ListCellRenderer() {
             @Override
             public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                  return button;
             }
    });
```

Add your items as follows: 
// doesn't matter what value are you adding, you will decide what information do you need when rendering an item

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 99; j++) {
        dataModel.add(j, j); 
    }
```

And an example using this: [How To Create custom JList](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/UseJListcomponenttodisplaycustomobjectswithListCellRenderer.htm)

**Edit**: some other useful references: 
[Drag and drop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html)
[Drag and drop inside JList](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DragandDropJListandList.htm)