# Icon in JTable Cell Causing Misrendering

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer

I'm trying to use a custom renderer to set the background of individual cells to a given image. In this case, I'm giving a chessboard wooden squares.

Here's what it looks like before:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i85nG.jpg]

Here's what it looks like afterwards:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho4Q5.jpg]

**EDIT**: With a little experimentation, it seems that every square is given the wood icon. Pieces can still be moved, resulting in this: (put it in the comments because I can't post more than 2 links)

In my code, I've merely replaced the `setBackground(darkSquare)` with `setIcon(wood)`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BoardCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private ArrayList<Coordinate> possibleMoves = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
    private ImageIcon wood = new ImageIcon("resources/images/light_square.png");

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        Color darkSquare = new Color(125, 125, 125);

        //pattern for the chessboard look
        if(row % 2 == 0 && column % 2 == 1)
            setBackground(darkSquare);
            //setIcon(wood);
        else if(row % 2 == 1 && column % 2 == 0)
            setBackground(darkSquare);
            //setIcon(wood);
        else
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        for(Coordinate move : possibleMoves)
            if(column == move.getX() && row == move.getY()){
                setBackground(new Color(255, 51, 51, 50));
                System.out.println("Highlighting (" + row + ", " + column + ")");
            }

        if(hasFocus){
            setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, Color.RED));
            System.out.println("hasFocus [array]: " + row + ", " + column);
            System.out.println("hasFocus [coordinate]: " + column + ", " + row);
        }
        if(isSelected)
            setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, Color.BLUE));


        return this;
    }

    public void setPossibleMoves(ArrayList<Coordinate> possibleMoves){
        this.possibleMoves = possibleMoves;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZw7r.jpg

Comment: don't to use renderer for this job, Icon / ImageIcon should be stored in the XxxTableModel, then XxxRenderer is responsible to painting image from model and backgroung of the chessboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it seems that every square is given the wood icon.

The renderer remembers its last state.

So maybe something like:

```
//  set the default values

setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
setIcon(null);  

if(row % 2 == 0 && column % 2 == 1)
    //setBackground(darkSquare);
    setIcon(wood);
else if(row % 2 == 1 && column % 2 == 0)
    //setBackground(darkSquare);
    setIcon(wood);
```

Of course you will still have a problem when you want to display a chess piece on top of the wood as you will want to render two icons, one for the background and one for the chess piece.

I'm not sure if a JTable is the best component to use for this. It might be easier to use a JPanel with a grid of either JPanel/JLabel to represent the wood square. Then you add a JLabel with an Icon of the chess piece to the square. This posting of a simple [Chess Board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674268/how-do-i-make-my-custom-swing-component-visible) might give you some ideas.

Edit:

> Would that be why the cell looks like it's printing ...?

Probably. The default for a JLabel is to display the icon followed by the text.

You can change this behaviour by using:

```
setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
```

in the constructor of your renderer. Then the text will be centered over the icon.

Comment: Is it possible to simply paint the image to the background of the cell versus filling it with a designated image? I can see how the grid of JLabels would work better (and I even considered doing it before), but I'm not sure how to make it as easy to use as the JTable already is.

Comment: It is the job of the renderer to paint the cell of the table. The table invokes the renderer whenever the cell needs to be painted.

Comment: So by setting the icon I'm overwriting the text stored in the cell? Would that be why the cell looks like it's printing `...`? Is the text-representation of the image being concatenated to the character used to represent the piece and thus filling the cell with a long string that is abbreviated by `...`?

Comment: @user5705019, see edit. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.